# C++ ADO built on WIN64 doesn't work on win32 OS

Tags: c++, ado

Hello I have built a C++ application that uses ADO to connect to MS ACCESS 2007: the provider is `MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` on my laptop which runs Windows 7 Professional 64 bit.

Everything is ok it works like a charm.

The problem is: if I move this application with the database to another machine running windows x86 it doesn't work! Please don't suggest the location of the database is the problem.

- If I move it to a win x64 it works keep in mind I built the project as a win32 application on my x64 machine.
- If i build the very code on a win32 machine it works both there and on a win 64 machine.
- So I guess the problem is due to ado dll on win64 doesn't work on win32.
- So how can I figure it out: to build an C++ ado application on win64 that works on win32 and win64 OSs?

Here is a sample of code:

```
#include <afxdisp.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#import "C:\\Program files\\Common Files\\System\\ado\\msado15.dll"\
    no_namespace\
    rename("EOF", "adoEOF")

try{
    bool m_IsConnectionOpen = false;
    _ConnectionPtr pConnection;

        HRESULT hr = pConnection.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Connection));
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Create Instance Succeeded!", 0, 0);
        hr = pConnection->Open(_bstr_t(L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;\
            Data Source=bin.accdb;"),
            _bstr_t(""),
            _bstr_t(""),
            adModeUnknown);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr)){
            MessageBox(NULL, "Connection Succeeded!", 0, 0);
            m_IsConnectionOpen = TRUE;
        }
        else
            MessageBox(0, "Connection  failed", 0,0);
}
catch(_com_error& e){
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPSTR)e.Description(), 0, 0);
}
catch(...){
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unhandled Exception!", 0, 0);
}
```

- I don't get success or failure of `CreateInstance`

Comment: *it doesn't work* is not a useful problem description. In what way does it not work? Do you get an error message? If so, what is the exact error you're getting? Does your app crash? If so, what exception or error messages do you get? We can't see your screen from where we're sitting.

Comment: @KenWhite: It doen't crash it is ok. but the problem is in `Connection` and thus I can't get any message from exception handling.

Comment: You have the information about your `Connection` right in front of you, and you've provided **zero information** about it in your question. How do you expect us to help you when you give us **absolutely no details** to use to do so? You've given us **no details** about **anything at all**. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to add details that we can use to try to help. With no details, your question has no value for future readers here and should be closed.

Comment: @KenWhite: I added code I think the problem is not in connection but maybe in the `COM DLL` while registering the application or some sort of thing..

Comment: You ignore the value of `hr` if `Succeeded()` fails. Why? If it failed, you need to find out why instead of just showing a messagebox with *else* in it. What does `hr` contain when `Succeeded` fails?

Comment: @KenWhite: Ok I'll edit it immediately right after I rebuild the application checking the value of success.

Comment: @KenWhite: I don't get any message!!!!

Comment: I have no idea what that means `hr` is an `HRESULT`, which means it contains a numeric value. There is no **message** for a numeric value. That value gives you something to use in a Google search to try and figure out what it means. Raise an exception with that value, put it in a message box, write it to a file, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why people are so negative?: When they cannot provide a clear explaining they `vote down`!

I managed to figure it out this way:

1- Go to my desktop computer windows 32 bit and copy the folder: 
`C:\program files\common files\system\ado` to my laptop's windows7 64 bit and paste in my project so my project looks like:

`C:\users\myUserName\Desktop\AdoProj\ado`

2- Now when I import the dll I import the new one (in my project folder ado):

`#import C:\\users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\AdoProj\\ado\\msado15.dll \
    no_namespace \
    rename("EOF", "adoEOF")`

Now the program runs on both win64 and win32 systems But I don't think that this a correct solution "using win32 dlls in win64" SO is there any clear solution?